# Very interesting! Mysql do not support &#119924; ？who know why?

Tags: mysql

In firefox you can see *M* of  𝑴 but can not see in IE8.

HEX is f09d91b4

And google can convert it to M from %F0%9D%91%B4.

Only see two blank square in notepad.

who know why?

Comment: SO doesn't support it as well. Probably something to do with encoding.